# 'Gmail Operation not allowed' exception after multiple calls to Gmail operations; how to avoid?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that basically searches a folder for emails received before a certain date (uses a GmailApp call for the search multiple times in one iteration) and then moves those messages to the Trash using a GmailApp call.

My script runs based on time, so after 15 minutes it will end and just install another trigger to it a bit later. So the script will be searching and moving emails for about an hour or 1.5 hours (with multiple triggers installed). The folder in which I search gets a lot of automated emails that I don't need after a week or two, hence why i want the script.

do you know why I would get a GmailApp exception that says Gmail does not allow that operation when I know it does?

Is it a quota issue? I got around the runtime quota issue but I don't know what else it could be.

I guess another question is, is there a JS function or call that will let me delete GmailThreads?

Edit: Adding the block of code

```
    var num_threads = search_threads.length;
    var num_deleted = 0;
    var countGmailX = 0;

//run for 15 minutes so we don't get time error
    console.info('Entering the While Loop');

    while (check_time(timenow)){

      num_threads = search_threads.length;
      GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(search_threads);
      countGmailX = countGmailX + 1; 

      num_deleted = num_deleted + 75;

      if (num_threads > 0){

        search_threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0 , 75);
        countGmailX = countGmailX + 1; 

      } else {
        console.info('No more Threads left to delete, exiting While Loop');
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('Exited While Loop');
    console.log('number of times GmailApp functions called: ' + countGmailX);

    search_threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 75);
    countGmailX = countGmailX + 1;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code where you interact with the GmailApp?

Comment: Would you be better served by using the `GmailApp.search({query})` feature instead of recursively going through emails to find something?  If you experiment with this you can test out different queries within gmail before putting them in your script.  Here is the link to the [GmailApp Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)).  `{thread}.moveToTrash()` will delete an entire thread where `{thread}` is just to denote the thread (either by ID or as a result of the query above) that you would like to delete.

Comment: Did it happen only once? Which line of your code threw you this exception? What as your total daily trigger runtime at this point?

Comment: @Rob I am using GmailApp.search, I set it to search 75 threads at a time. I have a large number of emails to move - the number is usually 500-1500 a day. I am moving the entire thread to the trash. I'll show you a block of code

Comment: @ziganotschka It was throwing it near midday after about 3 triggers were run. for two days. Each trigger for runs about 15 minutes each (3-4)

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly about what the total trigger runtime was, but be aware that there is a limit of 90 min maximum trigger runtime per day: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas When it comes to Gmail API, there are also daily limits for the usage of different methods https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Comment: @ziganotschka Is that 90 min limit just for 1 trigger or all the triggers ran in one day?

Comment: For all triggers together. 90 minutes is for free users (if you have a GSuite account it is more), so if you pass the limit this could be the reason for the exception.

Comment: i'm on a Gsuite for business account so i always figured i had more time

Comment: I see a possible issue with how your while loop is set up -- the call to delete the threads is at the beginning of the while loop instead of at the end of the while loop so the `if num_threads>0` is not as useful where it is at the moment.  If following your code correctly, this if statement should be right after the the `GmailApp.search` within the while loop, otherwise I believe that you would be running the search at least one iteration more than necessary.  Is there any way that you can provide us with the query?

Comment: For how long have you had your GSuite account? Note that for the first billing cycle you will still be subject to the consumer limit.